# Storing contents of environment within align

Tags: environments, amsmath

Now  we are at it here is another one that has been puzzling me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ}
\def\storer#1{\def\data{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{test}{\Collect@Body\storer}{%
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \data
  \end{pmatrix}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This works
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{test}
  a & b \\ c & d
 \end{test}
\end{equation*}
This does not
\begin{align*}
\begin{test}
  a & b \\ c & d
\end{test}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Reason, I'd like to make scalable matrices, i.e. I do not want to add `\scalebox{...}{....}` around matrices, that is not a good user interface.

Currently I'm using a solution that make use of `lrbox` and `varwidth`, it works but it is not pretty.

Joseph Wright mentioned that it may have something to do with the double typesetting witchcraft that `align` is doing

Ideas?

Comment: The `&` inside `test` confuse the alignment parser. It works if you enclose the `test` (pseudo)environment in braces.

Comment: again, nasty user interface ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simplest is to use

```
\begin{align*}
{\begin{test}
  a & b \\ c & d
\end{test}}
\end{align*}
```

with the extra brace group so it works.

the reason this fail is essentially that the outer alignment doesn't know that the test environment is an alignment so the `&` are taken as part of the outer alignment and things go wrong.

It's probably possible to avoid the need for the explicit group by adding some

```
  \ifnum0=`}\fi
```

groups somewhere but the AMS alignments are fragile beasts (that are already collecting the environment body to measure things, so doing it again inside is a bit delicate (and potentially inefficient) You might be better to hook into the `\if@mesuring` information and extract data that align has already collected rather than re-measuring.

---

version with `ifnum` groups added:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ}
\def\storer#1{\def\data{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{test}{%
\iffalse{\fi\ifnum 0=`}\fi
\Collect@Body\storer}{%
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \data
  \end{pmatrix}%
  \ifnum0=`{}\fi
}


\begin{document}
This works
\begin{equation*} \begin{test}  a & b \\ c & d \end{test}\end{equation*}
This does not
\begin{align*}
\begin{test}
  a & b \\ c & d
\end{test}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how does it get around this with the matrix constructions?

Comment: they use funky grouping to hide the inner alignment: see updated code

Comment: Very cool, that will work so much nicer than the `lrbox` + `varwidth` solution I've been using. I'll pass it on to Will, it might be a useful trick to mention in the environ manual.